# Firestore query with a boolean return function returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

this is my Firestore function:

```
export const keyExists = (setKey, keyExi) => {
  duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", setKey)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      keyExi((querySnapshot) => !querySnapshot.empty );
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
          player2: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

Its working correctly. Only the `keyExi((querySnapshot) => !querySnapshot.empty );` is returning undefined, when Im calling it in another .js document like this:

```
    const MainScreen = () => {
     const [keyExisting, keyExi] = useState(null);
    return (
    ...
      <CreatedButton
                    text="Apply"
                    onPress={() => {
                      keyExists(code,keyExi)
                      if (keyExisting == true) {
                        Alert.alert(
                            "Game joined"
                          );
                      } else if (keyExisting == false){
                        Alert.alert(
                          "Game does not exist or someone has already joined"
                        );
                       
                      }
                    }}
                  />
    ...
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are passing a **function** to keyExi: `keyExi((x) => ! x.empty))`.  In your code you are using the name `querySnapshot` for the parameter to the function, but in effect it is identical to the code I wrote.

The issue is that your function definition is declaring a new `querySnapshot` variable that is used in the function...it is not using the *existing* variable named `querySnapshot`.

What I suspect you want to do is change that line to be:  `keyExi(! querySnapshot.empty)`

You don't want to pass a function to `keyExi`.  You want to pass the calculated value `!querySnapshot.empty`.

BTW: I always recommend to my developers that for state variables we use the naming scheme:  `const [keyExisting, setKeyExisting] = useState()`.  That way, all of my "set functions for state variables" are easily recognizable.  Having function names that are different permutations of the state variable name (or worse...completely independent names) makes for difficult debugging and maintenance down the road.